# Swift superclass/subclass view controller variables

Tags: ios, arrays, inheritance, swift

I have a superclass `UIViewController` that contains this:

```
var results: [AnyObject] = []
```

I also have other methods in the superclass that's based on the content of `results` array.

I then have subclasses that inherit from this superclass, by loading data from REST API to populate `results` array with various types of data.

I currently don't override `results` array in subclass' `viewDidLoad()` or any other method. I simply clear the array using `results = []` and then load the array with a specific class type, such as a custom class `Product` or `String`.

```
results.append(Product())
```

I've been intermittenly getting crashes, but I can't tell why. I suspect it's due to the way the inheritance is working. Am I doing this correctly? Should I be overriding `results` in an `init()` method of the subclass or using `override var?

Comment: I think there are some mistakes in your question. Did you create a brand new `UIViewController` class? Because you can't add a stored property to an existing class (for which you don't have the source code), or override a property in a method. Or maybe you are confusing _superclass_ and _subclass_ with something else. Probably some code would help... Also, it would be good to know **where** the crash happens

Comment: Pasting crash stack trace here doesn't hurt anyone.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to the code right now. I can post later. The superclass is a new class that subclasses uiviewcontroller. It contains a table view that also implements the table delegates. The subclass defines how specific types of tables are loaded. And it crashes at results.append().

Comment: I also am trying adding `lazy` to the var's. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think typecasting can work here.
Try to do this in your **subclasses**:

```
class SubClass: SuperClass {
    private var _results: [Product] = []
    override var results: [AnyObject] {
        get {
            return _results
        }
        set {
            _results = newValue as! [Product]
        }
    }
}
```

But `Product` must be a class and not struct or enum.
Also as `String` does not conform to `AnyObject` you cannot save `String`s in `results` array.